# Discrepancy in Container VS HardBones Syscall usage [Linux]

Tags: assembly, containers, 64-bit, intel

I wasn't sure if this would be better on Security Stack overflow , but because this is involving code and I am potentially expecting a code answer , I will write here.

I wrote some Assembly for Linux that will make a DNS request and get back the response . The x86 version works everywhere, but when I made the x64 version of this and it works everywhere except for in containers.

I decided to dive in more and I noticed that if I change the request type to TCP it will also do what I require just fine.

I debugged and I see that everything is setup on the stack properly but no request actually ever goes out.  Should the code be written differently despite it works on baremetal machines? Or is there a restriction that is commonly in place to prevent UDP SEND calls.

Edit:
I am working on Linux x64 ubuntu. I can show a TCP dump when it works but the problem is that when it doesn't work , there is no traffic at all; No packets are sent.

Edit2:

> Here is the registers on the **container** which hold the return after the send .

```
rax            0xffffffffffffffa1   -95
rbx            0x0  0
rcx            0xffffffffffffffff   -1
rdx            0x20 32
rsi            0x7fffffffe2b8   140737488347832
rdi            0x7  7
rbp            0x0  0x0
rsp            0x7fffffffe2b0   0x7fffffffe2b0
r8             0x7fffffffe2b0   140737488347824
r9             0x10 16
r10            0xd  13
r11            0x346    838
r12            0x5555555544f0   93824992232688
r13            0x7fffffffe3b0   140737488348080
r14            0x0  0
r15            0x0  0
rip            0x555555554668   0x555555554668 <main+104>
eflags         0x246    [ PF ZF IF ]
cs             0x33 51
ss             0x2b 43
ds             0x0  0
es             0x0  0
fs             0x0  0
gs             0x0  0
```

> On the **physical Machine** after the send syscall.

```
(gdb) info registers
rax            0x20 32
rbx            0x0  0
rcx            0x555555554668   93824992233064
rdx            0x20 32
rsi            0x7fffffffdda8   140737488346536
rdi            0x3  3
rbp            0x5555555546e0   0x5555555546e0 <__libc_csu_init>
rsp            0x7fffffffdda0   0x7fffffffdda0
r8             0x7fffffffdda0   140737488346528
r9             0x10 16
r10            0x2  2
r11            0x246    582
r12            0x5555555544f0   93824992232688
r13            0x7fffffffdea0   140737488346784
r14            0x0  0
r15            0x0  0
rip            0x555555554668   0x555555554668 <main+104>
eflags         0x246    [ PF ZF IF ]
cs             0x33 51
ss             0x2b 43
ds             0x0  0
es             0x0  0
fs             0x0  0
gs             0x0  0
```

>

```
section     .text
global      main   ;must be declared for linker (ld)



;The Message We want to send.
;AA AA 01 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 0A 72 6f 6f 74 6b 69 74 64 65 76 03 63 6f 6d 00 00 01 00 01


   ;DNS HEADER;
   ; AA AA - ID
   ; 01 00 - Query parameters
   ; 00 01 - Number of questions
   ; 00 00 - Number of answers
   ; 00 00 - Number of authority records
   ; 00 00 - Number of additional records
   ; DNS QUESTION --
   ; 07 - 'example' has length 7, ;so change this to be the length of domain ; keep in mind there are not '.' in the question.
   ; 65 - e
   ; 78 - x
   ; 61 - a
   ; 6D - m
   ; 70 - p
   ; 6C - l
   ; 65 - e

   ; 03 - subdomain '.com'  length 03  ; change this to be the length of type.

   ; 63 - c
   ; 6F - o
   ; 6D - m

   ; 00    - zero byte to end the QNAME 
   ; 00 01 - QTYPE 
   ; 00 01 - QCLASS

   ; DNS ANSWER!
   ; aa aa
   ; 81 80
   ; 00 01
   ; 00 01
   ; 00 00
   ; 00 00
   ; 07 65
   ; 78 61
   ; 6d 70
   ; 6c 65
   ; 03 63
   ; 6f 6d
   ; 00 00
   ; 01 00
   ; 01 c0
   ; 0c 00
   ; 01 00
   ; 01 00
   ; 00 12
   ; 8d 00
   ; 04 

   ; IP ADDRESS IN HEX -- 93.184.216.34
   ; 5d
   ; b8 
   ; d8
   ; 22



main:

        mov rax, 41                                ;Create Socket
        mov rdi, 2                                 ;AF_INET
        mov rsi, 2                                 ;Sock_DGRAM
        mov rdx, 0                                 ;flags
        syscall                                    ;CALL SYSCALL CREATE SOCKET ; Looks good!

        mov rdi, rax                            ; sockfd
; ####################### DNS REQUEST

mov rax, 0x0000000100010000
push rax 
mov rax, 0x6d6f6303656c706d
push rax 
mov rax, 0x6178650700000000
push rax 
mov rax, 0x000001000001AAAA
push rax 

; ############################### 

        mov rsi ,rsp
        mov rdx, 32 ; len of bytes    ; Google IP  port 53  INET Family       
        mov rax, 0x0101010135000002   ; 8.8.8.8.8 - 0x35 - 00 00 02 
        push rax
        mov rax, 44                             ; Send Syscall

        mov r8, rsp
        mov r9, 16
        syscall  ; This never Actually sends in containers for some reason.


; Now need to read the response!

        xor rax, rax   ; read syscall == 0x00
        push 100        ; Set out bytes to response to be higher!
        pop rdx         ; rdx = input size
        sub rsp, rdx
        mov rsi, rsp    ; rsi => buffer
        syscall

        add rsp, rax ; This will give us the top of the stack where the answer is stored.
        sub rsp, 0x4 ;
        mov rax, [rsp]
        mov ebx, eax 
        mov rax, rbx
```

Comment: You forgot to mention what container and what OS. Also provide strace and wireshark log.

Comment: I can get some gdb dump trace if that will help.

Comment: @Jester perhaps this would help me a lot. Do you know what error code -95 is? I am looking at  error codes but only -1 and -2 are mentioned numerically. Others are by name.

Comment: Linux system calls return the errno as a negative number on errors.  So it's "EOPNOTSUPP 95 /* Operation not supported on transport endpoint */"

Comment: Also, if you used `strace` on your program like Jester said, it would shown you the error code by name. And that the IP address you're using is 1.1.1.1 not 8.8.8.8.

Comment: I understand. the 1.1.1.1 was from testing something else. I am looking at the EOPNOTSUPP error to understand it. It baffles me that the code is fine on some machines and on others it doesn't work.